# Sequelize with sqlite auto increment strange errors. No error but no auto increment when I use AutoIncrement but error when I use autoIncrement

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a discord bot. With 2 slash commands. One command named /setup for adding the guildId and a adminChannel to the database. And one command named /onduty for adding the user, onduty and offduty time to the database.

The /setup command works fine. It's the /onduty command that gives problems. But my main problem is that the model for the database table that handles times. Gives a error when I try to autoIncrement.

Here is my guild.js file:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../utils/database.js';

import { Time } from './times.js'

const Guild = sequelize.define('guilds', {
    guildId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    adminChannel: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});

Guild.hasMany(Time, {
    foreignKey: 'guildId',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
})
Time.belongsTo(Guild, {foreignKey: 'guildId'});

export { Guild };
```

Here is my times.js file

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../utils/database.js';

const Time = sequelize.define('times', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        AutoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    guildId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        references: {
            model: 'guilds',
            key: 'guildId',
        }
    },
    user: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    onDutyTime: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    offDutyTime: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
});

export { Time };
```

Here is my sequelize database init file (database.js)

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    host: 'localhost',
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
    logging: true,
});

export {sequelize};
```

Here is a image of my database:
[database.sqlite file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWvKY.png)

Here is what I get when I use AutoIncrement: true in my times.js file:

```
(node:42984) [SEQUELIZE0002] DeprecationWarning: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (`guildId` VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, `adminChannel` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);  
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`guilds`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_guilds_1`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));      
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`times`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_times_1`)
```

Here is what I get when I use autoIncrement: true in my times.js file:

```
(node:125932) [SEQUELIZE0002] DeprecationWarning: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (`guildId` VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, `adminChannel` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`guilds`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_guilds_1`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error
    at Database.<anonymous> (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:185:27)
    at D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:50
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Query.run (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:12)
    at D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
    at async SQLiteQueryInterface.createTable (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:98:12)
    at async times.sync (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:942:7)
    at async Sequelize.sync (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:377:9) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));'  
  },
  original: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));'  
  },
  sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));',   
  parameters: {}
}

Node.js v21.6.1
```

And I got this error:

```
(node:213712) [SEQUELIZE0002] DeprecationWarning: The logging-option should be either a function or false. Default: console.log
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`; 
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `guilds`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guilds` (`guildId` VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY, `adminChannel` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`guilds`)
Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_INFO(`sqlite_autoindex_guilds_1`)
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `times`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error
    at Database.<anonymous> (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:185:27)
    at D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:50
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Query.run (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\sqlite\query.js:183:12)
    at D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:315:28
    at async SQLiteQueryInterface.createTable (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:98:12)
    at async times.sync (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:942:7)
    at async Sequelize.sync (D:\A - Discord Bots\DiscordBot-Template-Master\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:377:9) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));'  
  },
  original: [Error: SQLITE_ERROR: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error] {
    errno: 1,
    code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
    sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));'  
  },
  sql: 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT, `guildId` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES `guilds` (`guildId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `onDutyTime` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `offDutyTime` VARCHAR(255), `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `guildId`));',   
  parameters: {}
}

Node.js v21.6.1
```

I'm expecting to just get the table with a autoincrement on the id colum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword can only exist on a `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` field.

Your primary key is a *composite key* consisting of `id,guildId`, which doesn't really make sense: `(1,77), (2,55), (3,33)` is *just as unique* as an index on just `id`: `1, 2, 3`.

Keep `id` as your (singular, normal) primary key.
Change the `guildId` to be a regular indexed column, not part of the primary key.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I'm new to sql. (I haven't learned that much, I'm in the process of learning. I know how to do some things but thats using graphical interfases to create tables.)

Comment: I know what most of the stuff mean. But the "`(1,77), (2,55), (3,33)` is just as unique as an index on just `id:` `1, 2, 3``." Throwed me a bit off.

Comment: You have **two** columns marked as **the** primary key, so the value of the PK doesn't consist of _just_ the `id` column but it _also_ contains the value of `guildID`, so the index won't be filled with _integers_, but with _pairs of integers_ because it's a [composite](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys) primary key. That doesn't work in combination with auto increment, which already uniquely identifies a row (that's the whole point). Just set `id` as  your PK and not the combination of `ID` **and** `guildID`.

Comment: It solved my issue. But I get this error: `Executing (default): INSERT INTO `times` (`id`,`guildId`,`user`,`onDutyTime`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);
TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
    at Object.run (file:///D:/A%20-%20Discord%20Bots/DiscordBot-Template-Master/src/interactions/slashCommands/onduty.js:24:35)`

Will edit my question to add the onduty.js code

Comment: You should not; this is a separate issue and should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Okay. Forgot about that.